# Multiple maven web application

Tags: maven

This is the structure:

```
simple-project(pom)
    simple-common(jar)
    simple-web(war)  -->(depend on) simple-common
```

Now once I run maven-tomcat7-plugin `in simple-web` with goal `tomcat7:run`, it told me that it can not find `xxxx-simple-common-1.0.jar`.

While I have ran the `mvn install` inside `simple-common` to install it to my local repository, and I can find the jar in my local maven repository directory.

Do I miss anything?

---

Update POMs:

simple-project(pom.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>simple-project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <modules>
        <module>simple-web</module>
        <module>simple-common</module>
    </modules>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
        <javax.version>1.7</javax.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            ....
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>when-package</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>p</name>
                    <value>true</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>application.properties</exclude>
                            <exclude>logback.xml</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.7</source>
                        <target>1.7</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>proxy</id>
            <url>http://192.168.1.96:8888/nexus/content/groups/public//</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

simple-common(pom.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>simple-project</artifactId>
        <groupId>test</groupId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <artifactId>simple-common</artifactId>
</project>
```

simple-web(pom.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>test</groupId>
        <artifactId>simple-project</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>simple-web</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>simple-common</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        ....
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>win</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <descriptors>
                                <descriptor>src/main/assembly/win.xml</descriptor>
                            </descriptors>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <port>8080</port>
                    <path>/web</path>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Please post all your POM's.

Comment: where is <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
defined?

You have these defined in the parent.
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
        <javax.version>1.7</javax.version>
    </properties>

Comment: The configuration you mentioned is defined at `simple-web` module which inherit the `simple-project`

Answer (score 0):

For guys who meet the same problem, I found "Install the parent project" is necessary.

Which means install `simple-common` is not enough, you may have to install `simple-project` as well, then you can run `tomcat:run` plugin in the `simple-web` module.

While I suspect with this logic, when I tried to run `tomcat:run` which means I am DEBUGGING this module, it is not stable yet, but I HAVE to install a un-stable artifact to repository before I can debug. This logic seems strange